# Should users have multiple groups?

Tags: database-design, cakephp

I am working on a personal / for fun project.  I am using cakePHP but this is more of a database design question.

Currently I have a field called group in my USERS table.  I have a GROUPS table that list several groups like admin, confirmed, new etc...

I also have a NOTIFICATIONS table that I use to track different types of notifications.  I want to add a field in the NOTIFICATIONS table for group, where group is from the GROUPS table.

The problem is if I tag a notification as being part of the "confirmed" group, how do I make sure users in the "admin" group also have access to it.  Essentially I want "admins" to have access to everything "confirmed" do, and more.

1) Would it be better to allow users to be part of multiple groups.  So a admin is in both the admin and confirmed group?

2) Should I have some extra logic in my code.  Like a function that I can pass a "group" to and it will tell me if the user has access to that group?

3) ...  Other approaches? I am thinking about this wrong?

Comment: You may want to elaborate on your spec a bit more. Is this for access as well as communication? What are some use cases for a user/group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that hard to let users be in multiple groups. You just need a `users_groups` table that has a `user_id` column and a `group_id` column.

The bigger question is: does it *make sense* for your application to do this? What are the reasons to do it? What are the reasons *not* to do it?

Also, I'm not sure what "confirmed group" means, but that sounds more like a status indicator than a true "group". But without knowing the detailed requirements, it's hard to say for sure.

---

Update:

If *only* admins will have the possibility to be in multiple groups, then it might be better to only allow users to be in one group. Then to indicate if a user is also an admin, you might want to have an `is_admin` indicator. Of course, the admins will still have to be in *some* group (unless you allow users to be in zero groups) so you could also put them in the "admin" group. Or is this a situation where an admin is only an admin of *some groups, but not all? In that case, you could have a table of `admins_groups` which has a `user_id` of an admin, and a `group_id` of the group they administer. Multiple records for the same `user_id` allows the admin user to administer very specific groups.

So... does it make sense for your users to be in multiple groups? If not now, is it something you may want in the future?

Comment: Technically speaking, this should be `groups_users` to follow the [CakePHP DB Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions) for join tables.

Comment: @Jason McCreary: Thanks, I don't know CakePHP conventions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I guess what I am really asking is.  Is it appropriate to allow users to be in multiple groups simply as a mechanism to give "admins" access to permissions associated with other groups.  Or should this be handled in a different way.

Comment: Thanks Frustrated...  It looks like I have some thinking to do about exactly what I want.  My question was not very well formed, but I appreciate your input.